# mysqli multi_query in laravel 5.7

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to make a query of two or more different tables to the database with **Laravel**

```
"SELECT * FROM table1";
"SELECT * FROM table2";
```

Is there any way to do this in Laravel?

something similar to this [mysqli::multi_query](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: Is there any good reason not just to execute two queries?

Comment: This may help you: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries

Comment: @RyanNerd I have read the documentation and can not find anything similar to what I intend.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine multiple queries (Laravel 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977933/combine-multiple-queries-laravel-5)

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution like this in laravel. but alternatively, you can use Laravel Eloquent Relations.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships

This may help you.